# XPath: How to select all sibling nodes up to one fulfilling some condition?

Tags: java, xpath, xhtml

I am trying to write me an XPath-expression returning all sibling nodes up to one, that satisfies a specific condition. In my specific case I have an (X)HTML list with list-items of which some have a specific class and other elements that have no class.

To visualize:
I am standing at one of the list items that DO have a class "foo" (e.g. the li containing the text "D" and I want to get a list of the subsequent li's containing "E", "F" and "G", but none of the subsequent items containing "H", "I" and "J".

```
...
<li class="foo">A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
<li class="foo">D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
<li>G</li>
<li class="foo">H</li>
<li>I</li>
<li>J</li>
...
```

I am standing at one of the list items that DO have a class "foo" (e.g. the li containing the text "D" and I want to get a list of the subsequent li's containing "E", "F" and "G", but none of the subsequent items containing "H", "I" and "J".

I am using Java v1.8 and its built-in javax.xml.xpath package accessing a previously parsed org.w3c.dom.Document.

Note: I have googled extensively for a solution and I am aware that there are quite a number of very similar looking examples, even here on StackOverflow, but none of these worked for me! Whatever I tried and adapted to the case at hand always gave me just the first element only ("E" in this example) or none at all. :-(

**Later addition:**

Since I apparently expressed myself so badly, I am appending a test-program:

```
package pull_lis;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy;

public class TestXPathExpression
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

        Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(new FileInputStream("sample.xml"), System.out);

        XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("//li[@class='foo']");

//      XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("//li[@class='foo'][2]/following-sibling::li[@class='foo'][1]/preceding-sibling::li[preceding-sibling::li[@class='foo'][2]]");
        XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("???"); // <<<< IT IS THIS EXPRESSION THAT I AM SEEKING

        NodeList foos = (NodeList)expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(foos.getLength() + " foos found.");

        for (int idx1 = 0; idx1 < foos.getLength(); idx1++) {
            Node foo = foos.item(idx1);
            System.out.println("foo[" + idx1 + "]: " + foo.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr2.evaluate(foo, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int idx2 = 0; idx2 < nodes.getLength(); idx2++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(idx2);
                System.out.println(non-foo[" + idx2 + "]: " + node.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

sample.xml contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="foo">A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li class="foo">D</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>F</li>
            <li>G</li>
            <li class="foo">H</li>
            <li>I</li>
            <li>J</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I let the above program run on sample.xml using the expression provided by kjhughes I get:

```
3 foos found.
foo[0]: A
non-foo[0]: E
non-foo[1]: F
non-foo[2]: G
foo[1]: D
non-foo[0]: E
non-foo[1]: F
non-foo[2]: G
foo[2]: H
non-foo[0]: E
non-foo[1]: F
non-foo[2]: G
```

but what I want/need is:

```
3 foos found.
foo[0]: A
non-foo[0]: B
non-foo[1]: C
foo[1]: D
non-foo[0]: E
non-foo[1]: F
non-foo[2]: G
foo[2]: H
non-foo[0]: I
non-foo[1]: J
```

Hope I could make myself a bit clearer this time...

M.

Comment: What is the "specific condition" you wish to test for?  Do you wish to test for the second <li> node that has the class "foo" or do you wish to test for the node that has the text "D".

Comment: So should the answer be based off a scenario where you are searching for what is between D and H or should it be based off a scenario where you are searching for what is between the 2nd and 3rd node with the class of "foo".

Comment: I wish to test for the second <li>-node that has a class "foo".

Answer (score 3):

**Given this XHTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="foo">A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li class="foo">D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li class="foo">H</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
</ul>
```

**This XPath:**

```
//li[. = 'D']/following-sibling::li[@class='foo'][1]/preceding-sibling::li[preceding-sibling::li[. = 'D']]
```

**Will return those `li` after the starting `<li>D</li>` but before the next `li` with `class='foo'`:**

```
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
<li>G</li>
```

---

### Update

OP has stated in comments that the first node of interest should be marked not by its contents of "D" but by being the second `li` with `@class="foo"`.

**Here is the above XPath that starts per this new criteria:**

```
//li[@class='foo'][2]/following-sibling::li[@class='foo'][1]/preceding-sibling::li[preceding-sibling::li[@class='foo'][2]]
```

**It selects the "E", "F", and "G" `li` elements as requested.**

Comment: @harshtuna: You'll have to explain what you mean as I see no requirement regarding `H` other than that the result should include *none of the subsequent items containing "H", "I" and "J"*, and this result does not indeed include "H".

Comment: I think he means if you were to search for items after H instead of for items after D in the given XHTML then the xpath would not return I and J as there is no subsequent "foo" node.  Its not explicitly stated as a requirement in the  question so I'm not sure if its valid.

Comment: Ok, but that's a bit far afield from OP's stated requirements.

Comment: yes, exactly what Nick explained. if the only goal to get E, F, G - `//li[. = 'E' or .='F' or .='G']` is even an easier solution ;) which is apparently wrong

Comment: Gentlemen: I invite you both to submit answers that meet your interpretation of OP's question.  Thanks.

Comment: The text is variable - I only provided this as example so I can refer to different nodes to explain the problem. But I need a solution that only relies on the class name.

Comment: Then you need another way to specify which `li` with `@class='foo'` marks the first `li` of interest.  So far, you yourself have referenced it only by referencing its content, "D".

Comment: I see in a new comment to the question that you've stated that you want to start at the *second*  `li` with `@class='foo'`.   I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Sorry for having expressed myself so badly! That second "li" was also only meant as an example.
What I want is all <li>-nodes following a given li[@class='foo']-node up to but not including the subsequent li[@class='foo']-node.

Comment: @mmo, everything cannot just be an example.  You need to state an **objective criteria** for determining "***a given li[@class='foo']-node***".  On this, your third attempt, you've *still* failed to that.  Sorry, but I'm bowing out here.  Good luck.

Comment: @kjhughes I regret that, but many thanks for attempting to help, anyway! 

How objective sounds this: "Given is a list of <li>-nodes, some of which have a class='foo' attribute. Selecting any of these special nodes as a starting point the result should be a sub-list of all <li>-nodes that follow that starting <li class='foo'>-node till (but not including) the subsequent <li class='foo'>-node (or the end of the list)?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to remember all my XPath 1.0 programming tricks, and I've come to the conclusion it can't be done in a single XPath 1.0 expression. That's a bold statement and someone may prove me wrong.

But since you're in Java, you're not restricted to XPath 1.0. Get yourself an XPath 2.0 library (e.g. Saxon), then you can write

```
for $N in following-sibling::li[@class='foo'][1] 
return following-sibling::li[. << $N]
```

Alternatively, since you're using DOM (why does anyone use DOM nowadays?) just iterate over the following siblings in your Java code until you find the one that matches.

Comment: >> why does anyone use DOM nowadays? Well - because I can have XPath operate on it. :-)

Comment: Background: I am following a couple of online magazines offering access via table of content pages linking to the misc. chapters. Such "manual tree-traversals" are annoying and I thus want a tool to generate a pre-fetched, linear "printer-friendly" version thast can be read offline (e.g. while riding the bus or train).

I want the conditions for identifying the TOC, the individual links and the actual chapters' contents configurable using XPath to be able to tailor the program to different sites. Hardcoded stuff may work on one site but will probably fail on an other.

Comment: Can't see any reason for using Java/DOM there. Sounds just the job for XSLT.

Comment: You might be right. I simply never had XSLT do more than translate one input into one output. Here I want to combine 150+ webpages into a single linear page and thought, doing this programmatically might be simpler. But I guess, XSLT could somehow handle that, too. Maybe time to reconsider...